# Why do I get the error "You don't have permission to access / on this server."?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose, yii2-advanced-app

I try to run my site on docker and this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
    image: yiisoftware/yii2-php:7.1-apache
  volumes:
    - ~/projects/my-project-name.local/composer- 
    docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
    - ./:/app:delegated
  ports:
    - '8000:80'
```

When I run "docker-compose up -d --build" and open an url localhost:8000 the error occured "Forbidden.You don't have permission to access / on this server."
The logs of container is:

```
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html] does not exist
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.22.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html] does not exist
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.22.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Jul 10 06:42:22.442648 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 10 06:42:22.442713 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Jul 10 06:42:25.985025 2018] [core:error] [pid 17] [client 172.22.0.1:48650] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html
172.22.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2018:06:42:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
[Tue Jul 10 06:42:26.117774 2018] [core:error] [pid 17] [client 172.22.0.1:48650] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html, referer: http://localhost:8000/
172.22.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2018:06:42:26 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 513 "http://localhost:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
```

When I use same docker-compose.yml with yii2 basic everything works fine.
Please help me to fix this problem. My OS is Ubuntu-18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the yii2 docker image is based on the php image and has the following lines in its Dockerfile:

```
# Copy the app code into the image
COPY . /var/www/html
```

This is consistent with the warning from the logs.

When you add this to your Dockerfile, you should be fine (Assuming you have your source code in the current directory).

If you want to use the docker container as a development environemt, you could instead mount the folder of the source code to `/var/www/html`. In that case you have to add a volume:

```
volumes:
  - .:/var/www/html # Add this line
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have only docker-compose.yml, is it neсessary to use dockerfile?

Comment: It depends. Do you want to edit your source files and use docker as a development server? In that case you can just mount the current folder to `/var/www/html` as a volume.

Comment: Thank you, I understood now